# Is it possible to embed the Collection Editor of a Property Grid inside a panel?

Tags: .net, propertygrid, collectioneditor

the standard behaviour is to launch it in a new window.

[image]

is there any way that form could be embedded inside another form's panel? Basically to have the PropertyGrid and the Colelction Editor standing side by side in a form?